# Several UINavigation controllers, one for each tab, as an outlets from my app delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This is more of a discussion on an issue and my implementation, which seems to be causing issues.

My app has a tab bar and navigation controllers. Within each tab you can go into views, and the tab bar will be hidden until you click back from your sub view.

I have a navigation controller for each on my tabs, these are declared as outlets in my app delegate and also have `@class tab1navcontroller`

A typical use would be.

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
       delegate];
[delegate.tab1NavController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

I haven't had many problems with this in the past and I believe I copied the approach from a book I was reading at the time.

However, I had a discussion with a colleuge some months ago who said I should only have one navigation controller for my app.

At the time I did try and replace the code (shown above) and use `self.navigationcontroller` instead, but this caused problems, I can't remember what they were, but I discarded those fixes.

Today an error has occurred, when the view is pushed and back tapped quickly.
I also ran the app with the zombie profiler and this indicated the code above was the problem.

I believe the code above could be causing leaks.

I just don't know what approach is best and where to go from here ?

Comment: Your colleague was wrong. It is perfectly normal to have a navigation controller for each tab. He/she was probably mixing that up with a tab bar controller, which you should generally have one of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dima said in the comment, your colleague was wrong. In my app I have one tabbarController as the window rootViewController. You can either expose it in a property or its viewController array or the individual navigation controllers. You CANNOT reuse a navigation controller in multiple tabs - its one for each, or a mix. That is, in my tabbarController, I have 4 naviationControllers and one plain UIViewController subclass.

The tab bar controller retains the all its viewControllers, and the navigationControllers retain all their viewControllers. That said, you get into problems if you have a 'assign' type reference to a viewController that gets popped.

Comment: thanks. So is my usage call correct? Any idea why it's crashing and what I should do to fix this ?

Comment: No person on this planet who can tell you why its crashing from the information you have disclosed so far. The most likely your property is returning an address of a released object, or that the object you push is released. Click on the Breakpoints button in the toolbard. Look at the Scheme and insure that lldb is set. Click the BreakPoints icon left pane second from left, add a BreakPoint on all Exceptions. Run. Crash. LLDB will show you the line it crashes on. The object that is messaged or the parameter is probably the cause. You never said ARC or not. Update question with more info.

Comment: You accepted the answer - did you find the problem? If so add a comment here or update the Question so others will know what the problem (and fix) was. Thanks!

Comment: I figured you'd answered the question. I didn't think it was relevant to ask more. I haven't reached a fix but I call an alert view with a progress indicator while some data processing is running on return from the sub view. When plugged in and ran from my device, it seemed to hang on the alert view. That uses grand dispatch. The app hasn't been converted to use arc. I ran a check and it need a library updating. I'm hoping moving to arc will sort the problem.