# Receiver type for instance message is a forward declaration popToRootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've seen similar questions on this error.
But I'm not sure how it applies in this instance

This is the error

```
Receiver type for instance message is a forward declaration
```

And this is my code.

```
MyAppDelegate *appDel = (MyAppDelegate*) 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDel.secondTabNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

What's the problem here and how do I fix it ?

I clarified my usage of this code was correct, as a different navigation controller for each of my tabs in my tab controller. I do this as I push views within each controller.
[Several UINavigation controllers, one for each tab, as an outlets from my app delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609424/several-uinavigation-controllers-one-for-each-tab-as-an-outlets-from-my-app-de)

Comment: Is this really and error and not just a warning?

Comment: It's a warning, but in red, when I try to use the arc refactor tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to import the appdelegate.h and it should work fine.

A better way of implementing this would be to use notifications.
1. Send a notification when you reach the condition
2. Handle the notification in the appropriate view controller. (You can handle it in the app delegate too but it is not a clean way)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by using notifications ?

Comment: i was referring to [NSNotification](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_nsnotificationcenter/). quoting from the link "Triggering methods in disconnected objects would require some hefty coding without notifications and the NSNotificationCenter. By adding observers to listen for specific posts to the notification center, your objects can communicate and pass data easily."

Comment: oh you mean use the notification to display the alert view ?

Comment: which alert view are you talking about ? i dont see any reference to any alert views in the question. NSNotification is a system/user generated event. You can listen to these events by adding observers to a central NSNotification center. Then you handle the events accordingly.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't sure what you mean. What do I use the notification for?

Comment: `MyAppDelegate *appDel = (MyAppDelegate*) 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDel.secondTabNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Accessing the app delegate in this fashion is not a good practice. It makes the code tightly coupled. 

Instead, You could use NSNotification to generate an event at that point and then handle it appropriately

Comment: Hi Shashikanth. Thanks for the notification center tip! It helped me A LOT and I got hid of many App delegate calls.